# How to get files from different folders compress them and return them to mobile client from asp.net web api service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Actually I'm trying to return multiple files(within same response as result to jQuery mobile client request) which include(html, .js, .css, .png images files) altogether at one time so that mobile client can download them as new updates. And I have been asked to make it a POST request rather than a GET request anyway.
Here is my Web API code

```
       [Route("availableupdates")]
       [HttpPost]
       public HttpResponseMessage FilePackage()      
       {
         HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        var localFilePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp\Flower_Shop\Flower_Shop\images\i.png");
        if (!File.Exists(localFilePath[0]))
        {
          response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
      else
      {
          response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
          response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath[0], FileMode.Open,   FileAccess.Read));
          response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
          response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
          response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "i";                
      }
      return response;
    }
```

Now the thing is that all those (html, .js, .css, .png) files are part of another little mobile app (and apparently lying in different folders within same application) which is sitting on the same server as the Web API RESTFUL service itself and in the code above I just hardcoded  physical path of one of the image files. I don't know how to get all the files from different folders and sub-folders and compress them together and send them to the client.

Another big thing that I will really appreciate if someone explains me what MIMETYPE will work for the compressed files and do I need to send the compressed files as JSON response as I don't really know that It would be a good idea to send back a JSON response. What will happen to the contents of the files? Will the contents be converted into JSON as well?

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.5, have a look at the new compression capability in the framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This seems nice new capability, but what I'm wondering that if it would be hard for the JQuery mobile client to go into directories and sub directories inside the zip file and get all the files one by one, write their contents locally and save them locally.

Comment: And if I use this new capability what will be mime type of the zip file and how should I return this zip file? As JSON?